# Can you use the __init__ method as a setter on an object that's already been instantiated

Tags: python

After creating an instance object from a class, can you use the object's **init** method to set it's variable to something new?

Ex:

```
class Object1(Object):

    def __init__(self, name, ability):
        self.name = name
        self.ability = ability

example1 = Object1("example", "none")
#new object created with parameters set by the __init__ method 

example1.__init__("changeExample", "Changed")
#called the __init__ method on the object and changed the parameters.   Is this okay to do?
```

Comment: It's legal, but deeply unidiomatic.  It is very likely a bad idea.

Comment: It's generally better to have another method and have the `__init__` call *that*.

Comment: I'm completely new to learning how to code and am trying to learn python.  I was just curious, I know it doesn't really seem to have a use case but I wanted to know if there was anything else special about __init__ compared to other methods, or if this would cause a bug, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all of your responses.

Comment: If there were some reason you needed special behavior for setting an attribute, a more reasonable approach would be to write a setter and then call that setter from `__init__`.  Note that you generally don't need to write setters and getters in Python unless you do need some special behavior, since you can change an existing attribute into a property with arbitrary getting and setting code at any point.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me and sounds like a good workaround.